# Wave equation with mixed boundary conditions using D'Alembert

Tags: partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

The wave equation for a semi-infinite string with boundary conditions:
$$\begin{cases}u_{xx}=u_{tt} &x,t>0 \\ u_{x}(0,t)=au(0,t)+bu_{t}(0,t)+h(t) &t\ge 0 \\
u(x,0)=f(x) &x>0 \\ u_{t}(x,0)=g(x) & x>0\end{cases}$$

First, I wonder what the physical interpretation might be at $x=0$. Is it a motor $h(t)$, a spring with springconstant $a$ and vertical friction with the motor with friction constant $b$?

Second, I have to solve this problem using the general solution for the wave equation: $$u(x,t)=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$$ and $h=g=a=0$. I cannot figure out how the wave equation is solved at $x=0$ using the general solution and the method of characteristics.

Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you! I see it looks like overleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x-t)+f(x+t))+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}g(x_{0})dx_{0}$$

The standard solution for $u(x,t)$ for $c=1$ and $x_{0}$ a dummy variable. The derivative of $u(x,t)$ with respect to $x$ and $t$ are:

$$u_{x}(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(f'(x+t)+f'(x-t))$$
and
$$u_{t}(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(f'(x+t)-f'(x-t))$$
now
$$u_{x}(0,t)=b*u_{t}(0,t)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(f'(t)+f'(-t))=\frac{b}{2}(f'(t)-f'(-t))$$
The function $f(t)$ is known and therefore also the derivative $f'(t)$. The extension of $f(t)$ has to be determined.
$$f'(-t)=\frac{b-1}{b+1}f'(t)$$
To meet the boundary condition at $x=0$ the derivative of $f(t)$ has to be extended even around $x=0$ and multiplied with $\frac{b-1}{b+1}$, therefore $f(t)$ has to be extended uneven around $x=0$ and multiplied with $\frac{b-1}{b+1}$. The solution in the general form $u(x,t)=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$ is:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}f_{ext}(x-t)+\frac{1}{2}f_{ext}(x+t)$$
with $f_{ext}$ the uneven extension around $x=0$ mulitplied by $\frac{b-1}{b+1}$ of $f(t)$.